# jQuery TOOLS scrollable can't find its navigator

Tags: jquery, scrollable, navigator

So, got a little problem here :)

I'm using [jQuery TOOLS](http://flowplayer.org/tools/index.html) to make a neat, little scrollable gallery. Worked perfectly fine until i moved the correlating navigator **one node too far away** from the scrollable div.

Aaand.. now **they don't want to talk to each other** anymore.

Here we go with the code:

```
<section>
  <div class="scrollable"> 
    <div class="gallery_items">
      <div class="gallery"><!-- Stuff goes here --></div>
      <div class="gallery"><!-- the rest of it here --></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <div class="navigation">
    <a href="#1">1</a>
    <a href="#2">2</a>
  </div>
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.scrollable').scrollable({
    circular: false, keyboard: false
  }).navigator({
    navi: '.navigation', naviItem: 'a'
  });
</script>
```

Any idea how to connect the footer navigation so the scrollable, pleeeease? :)

Sincerely, Pakuna from germany!

Comment: It would really help if you had a demo of this problem at http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried rounding everything in:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //all your jquery goodness here
    $('.scrollable').scrollable({
        circular: false, keyboard: false
    }).navigator({
        navi: '.navigation', naviItem: 'a'
    });
});
```

Comment: Ye, all the scripts i use are embedded anyway. Just left the rest out to keep the example clean and easy to read. But that doesn't seem the fix my problem :<